# Java + GRPC, for dummies?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I have managed to clone the grpc-java from github and ran the gradlew script. Helloworld seems to be working and so on. However now I'm pretty much stuck. How can I continue developing on Eclipse? Is there somewhere a .jar file I need to add to my project? How does this work?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not how StackOverflow works. Ask specific questions.

Comment: Ok, I thought that my questions were specific enough.

Comment: Step by step tutorial Java + GRPC at https://bertrandszoghy.wordpress.com/2017/06/01/protocol-buffers-grpc-client-and-server-using-secure-channels-with-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cloned from the command line, you can import the project from eclipse (file->import->project->git->local repository)

But I would start reading eclipse basics before you get lost with gradle/maven and dependendencies.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to import the whole project but I did find the needed files from "grpc-java\examples\build\install\examples\lib" added those as external jar files and I'm good to go.